# Continuing a function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a VBA macro where it analyzes multiple sheets of data in the same excel file. I currently have it set so that when it's analyzing all the various sheets, when it finds an error, it stops the program completely. I have figured out how to get it to go to the next sheet but cannot get the program to continue running. Here is what I have so far:

```
    `If Counter > 480 Then
        Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
        End
    End If`
```

I know the End function ends running the program but when I take it out it does not work, how can I get the program to continue running as it was before it reaches the sheet with the error?

Comment: What do u want to do after the sheet is selected?

Comment: so you want the program to continue after it finds an error on the worksheet?

Comment: @Katana24 yes that's exactly what I want it to do

Comment: Please provide us with more context and code. If you want code to continue after an error you can use On Error Resume Next, or On Error Goto

Answer (score 0):

Put the loop that you want to end in a separate function or sub, then when the error is found, use

```
Exit Function
```

or

```
Exit Sub
```

if it's a sub.

Simple example using your code:

```
Sub Main
    OtherSub
    'Continue here
End Sub

Sub OtherSub
    If Counter > 480 Then
        Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Would that allow the program to continue to run? This is a small part of the macro and I have an end sub at the end of the entire vba macro

Comment: I updated my answer just now. If you put the part of the code you want to stop in a separate sub/function and run it from there, then if you use Exit Function it will go back to the previous sub/function that it came from and continue from there

Comment: So it would look like this?

  
`Sub Error
  If Counter > 480 Then
        Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
           End
           End If
           Exit Sub`

Sorry about the syntax

Comment: I updated again with an example. `End` is replaced with `Exit Sub`.